# Broadcom BCM4312 wireless card does not work in 11.04 but did (out of the box) in 10.10

Tags: 11.04, broadcom, hp

Here's my card :

> 02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

When I try to install the Broadcom STA wireless drivers through 'Additional Drivers', it says "installation failed" and tells me to look in `/var/logs/jockey.log`.

What can I do about it? Also, how can the Ubuntu devs be informed of this?

It's not like I'm running it on some obscure machine. It's an HP Pavilion laptop. Everything worked fine in Maverick.

Answer (score 2):

The STA driver in 11.04 doesn't work due to a kernel issue. You will have to install the B43xx firmware. Just install firmware-b43-installer from the software center or synaptic.

You can also do it from the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a corresponding bug report for this issue?

Comment: Couldn't find a bug report, but I did find this [Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/157521).